# Execute javascript code from java (with eclipse)

Tags: java, javascript

I need to call some javascript code from my java app, can I do such a thing?

thanks
adi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a third-party library like [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), but there is no straightforward way to invoke JavaScript code from Java.  Though the two have similar names, they have about as much in common as a car and a caramel.

More generally, having programs written in one language interact with languages written in another is often tricky due to the internals of the two programming language implementations not being compatible with another.  There are many exceptions to this rule and a lot of effort has been invested in making projects work in multiple languages, but there's often a high startup cost.

Comment: Well with either the Mozilla/Rhino integration libraries, or the JDK 1.6 "ScriptEngine" stuff, it actually is very straightforward to invoke JavaScript from Java. In fact the ScriptEngine facility can hand back objects wrapped around a ScriptEngine instance implementing any API you want, and from that object Java code can call JavaScript directly.

Comment: thanks i'll try it... i guess this is pretty much what im looking for...(:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, either by grabbing Rhino from Mozilla and using its integration libraries or by using the JDK 1.6 "ScriptEngine" facility.

The version of Rhino (the Mozilla-authored Java-implemented JavaScript engine) included with JDK 6 is pretty old and buggy, be warned.

Answer (score 0):

LiveConnect does this nicely, see the references and examples for JSObject. You'll probably be interested in [JSObject.eval](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web/jscript/refp_186.html), which will give you the ability to execute JavaScript code under the context of any JavaScript object.

Comment: I think the question here is about server-side Java code, not applets.